# How to create PDF preview in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the PdfViewerModule from ng2-pdf-viewer. I just wanted to have a display of the pdf file before or after it was uploaded. Is there are a way for me to get file which I uploaded on my web-application as a URL and paste that as the source of the pdf-viewer? Thanks!

```
        <pdf-viewer
            [src]="tmpPdfUrl" // paste here the URL of the uploaded file for preview
            [render-text]="true"
            [original-size]="false"
            [zoom]="1"
        ></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Got the answer already, you can use "URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])" and add that as the URL for the [src] attribute in the pdf-viewer on your HTML.